# How does application storage work on android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating an android application where a user can input their name, which would saved after closing out the application entirely. Do I need to do more work beyond just changing the methods like oneResume(), onPause(), etc. or is there a specific way to save this across sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to code for that. Good thing is Android provide apis for everything. You can use `SharedPreference` for saving data.

#### Store values in preference in `onPause()`:

```
// PREFERENCE_NAME - a static String variable like: 
//public static final String MY_PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "abc");
 editor.apply();
```

#### Retrieve data from preference `onResume()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
  String name = prefs.getString("name", "No name defined");//"No name defined" is the default value.
}
```

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

**Note that** if you want save huge data like a list of cities, then use database.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary

Comment: You can mark this right to users know, that you got your answer.

Comment: also one question, this will be implemented in the "main" activity, would there be any difference in performance between using editor.apply() vs editor.commit()? I looked into the difference btwn the two and ive read that you dont want to use commit() on your main thread.

Comment: Use `apply();` commit is not recommended from documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Session management can be done through SharedPreference. You have to store and retrieve the data according to the activity life cycle. As mentioned below